# PHP MySQL search for data in array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, code-injection

I'm doing a practice project setting up a basic social network. I have a table with user id, name, last name, and a friends column which contains the id numbers of all other 'users' that they are friends with. E.g. 3 "Donald" "Duck" "4, 5, 23, 42".
The following works if I know the values:

```
if(mysqli_connect_errno($con))  {
    echo "failed to connect" . mysql_connect_error();
} else {
    $resulting = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE LastName LIKE '%$secondquery%'
        OR LastName LIKE '%$firstquery%'
        OR LastName LIKE '%$thirdquery%'
        OR LastName LIKE '%$fourthquery%'
        OR FirstName LIKE '%$secondquery%'
        OR FirstName LIKE '%$firstquery%'
        OR FirstName LIKE '%$thirdquery%'
        OR FirstName LIKE '%$fourthquery%'
    ");
    $counting = mysqli_num_rows($resulting);

    if($counting != 0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resulting))
        {
            if($row['Profile'] != null) {
                $defaultprofilepic = $row['Profile'];
            }else {
                $defaultprofilepic = "defaultprofile.JPG";
            }
            $PublicProfile = $row['ProfilePage'];
            $Friends = array("4", "5", "23", "42") 
            if(in_array(42, $Friends)){
                echo $row['FirstName'] . " is your friend!";
            } else {
                echo "Connect with " . $row['FirstName'];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, I can't get the following working properly, regardless of how the data appears in the database (e.g. "1", "2", "42" or "1, 2, 3, 4" or 1 2 3 4 . If the 42 is the first in the list then it often does work, but that's not very helpful!

```
$Friends = array($row['Friends'];
if(in_array(42, $Friends)) {
    echo $row['FirstName'] . " is your friend!";
} else {
    echo "Connect with " . $row['FirstName'];
}
```

I'm aware there's probably a much better way of doing it, or even of storing the relevant data, so any suggestions are welcome! I also know that the following may be vulnerable to sql injection (as the "querys" are from a user search), but don't properly understand that yet so help on that would be great as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create new table eg 'friends', and contain in it, with structure like this: user_id | friend_id. It should look like this:

```
user_id | friend_id
    1   |     1
    1   |     2
    1   |     3
    2   |     4
```

And

```
SELECT * FROM friends WHERE user_id = $our_user_id
```

And use : [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) syntax.

*(Btw. better learn PDO)*

Comment: This is the way to do it (and as someone who is just learning SQL myself, I also find it super-frustrating that SQL doesn't support lists).  And I second learning PDO as well.  You can read about it here - http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/